# What is the meaning of this sloka?

Tags: identification-request, shloka

I heard the below shloka from my friend. The below shloka is:-

> ॐ बन्धूक कुसुमाभासां पञ्चमुण्डाधिवासिनीं।
> स्फुरच्चन्द्रकलारत्न मुकुटां मुण्डमालिनीं॥
> त्रिनेत्रां रक्त वसनां पीनोन्नत घटस्तनीं।
> पुस्तकं चाक्षमालां च वरं चाभयकं क्रमात्॥
> दधतीं संस्मरेन्नित्यमुत्तराम्नायमानितां।

My question is what is the meaning of this shloka?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the *dhyānamantra* of *Ḍāmarabhairavī* as per *Śrīvidyarṇava Tantra* (who is worshipped as the presiding deity of the *Navārṇa mantra* by Bengali Hindus). It is translated as follows

[image: Ḍāmarabhairavī]

> Remember Her who is respected in *Uttarāmnāya*, whose complexion is (as red) as the *bandhuka* (*Pentapetes phoenicea*) flower, who is seated upon a *Pañcamuṇḍa* seat (an earthen platform built upon 5 skulls of specific characteristics used by *purṇābhiṣikta sādhaka*s of *Kālīkula* for performing austerities), whose crown is illuminated by the gem in the form of the lunar digit, who wears a garland of human heads, who has 3 eyes, who wears red garments, whose uplifted breasts resemble pitchers, who holds in Her hands a book, a string of rosary & the *mudrā*s of blessing & fearlessness.